# writing output in the csv format from dictionary

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, output

Could I please get advice on how I might be able to write my output into the tab delimited format? I am comparing a csv file to a dictionary. Here is my code (this is the end of the code that I have an issue with):

```
import csv

file3 = open(r'file.csv','rt', newline = '')
baits = csv.reader(file3, delimiter = '\t')

file4 = open(r'file.txt','wt', newline = '')
common = csv.writer(file4, delimiter = '\t')

for line in baits:
    chromosome = line[0]
    start = int(line[1])
    end = int(line[2])
    if chromosome in dmc:
        for value in dmc[chromosome]:
            base = value[0]
            others = value[1:]
            if base >= start and base <= end:
                count_in += 1
                common.writerow(line + [base, others])

file3.close()
file4.close()
```

Here is a sample of my output:

```
chr1    3505353 3505472 3505390 (['3505390', '-', '3.32682966730502e-08', '1.69470366570212e-07', '-35.4239256678281', '1', '156190', 'NM_001011874', '-'],)                                        
chr1    3601312 3601671 3601347 (['3601347', '-', '1.94815734655407e-08', '1.01925267518696e-07', '-40.8010680907877', '2', '60233', 'NM_001011874', '-'],)
```

I am having problems trying to get rid of the braces and '' so that each value in the braces are tab separated.

Would anyone know the code can be modified to achieve that?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the point of file3 and file4 in your code? You are not using either in your data processor. Is `DMR_DMC` your output file? And if so does it reference a `csv.writer` object?

Comment: Sorry. that was a typo.

Comment: If you can't show us a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with complete data, can you at least do a `print(repr(line), repr(value))` and give us one example, so we know what types you're trying to output and what format they're in?

Comment: It would also be nice to know what the values in the `dmc` dictionary are -- lists, tuples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell without seeing your data here, but I'm guessing it looks something like this:

```
line = ['chr', 3505353, 3505472]
base = 3505390
others = (['3505390', '-', '3.32682966730502e-08', '1.69470366570212e-07', '-35.4239256678281', '1', '156190', 'NM_001011874', '-'],)
```

If so, `line + [base, others]` will be:

```
['chr', 3505353, 3505472, 3505390,  (['3505390', '-', '3.32682966730502e-08', '1.69470366570212e-07', '-35.4239256678281', '1', '156190', 'NM_001011874', '-'],)]
```

In other words, five columns, the last of which is a tuple containing a single list containing a bunch of values.

I don't know exactly what output you want, but I'd assume that each list in that tuple means a new row, and the list is just a bunch of extra columns. In which case:

```
if base >= start and base <= end:
    count_in += 1
    for other in others:
        common.writerow(line + [base] + others)
```

That would give you a row that looks like:

```
chr1    3505353 3505472 3505390 3505390 - 3.32682966730502e-08 1.69470366570212e-07 -35.4239256678281 1 156190 NM_001011874 -
```

At any rate, the only way to get the output you want is to get a list of column values. And it's a lot easier to debug getting a list right. Try printing out the pieces, and then work out what you'd have to do to put those pieces together into a single flat list. Once you have that, you're done.

Comment: Thanks. I went back trying out a couple of things printing out pieces. Solved it finally! Thanks for your help. You were spot on with your assumptions

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing—because your question lacks a lot of information—that you need to change this line:

```
            common.writerow(line + [base, others])
```

to this:

```
            common.writerow(line + list(value))
```

Also,`csv`files should be opened mode`'rb'`or`'wb'`.

Comment: This code will not work as DMR_DMC.writerow only takes a single argument. DMR_DMC.writerow(line + value) has two arguments. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/MethylKit output/Cortex_vs_Liver/Bait_DMC_merge.py", line 46, in <module>
    DMR_DMC.writerow(line + value)
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list

Comment: @user3302763: You're right that it won't work, but that's not the problem. `line + value` is still one argument; it's just not a legal argument because you're adding a list (`line`) and a tuple (`value`). You could fix that by doing `line + list(value)`. (I don't know if that's what you actually _want_, but it would at least not raise that exception.)